# How do I submit a villanelle in MLA style?

Tags: poetry, mla

I understand how to submit essays in MLA styles, but how do I submit a villanelle?

Comment: How exactly do you mean ‘submit’? Where are you submitting the villanelle to? And how is MLA styles relevant? Normally, villanelles and other forms of poetry do not require bibliographies and such things where style guides become important. Or did you mean to ask how to _cite_ a villanelle in MLA?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm submitting to my english teacher. Normally we write essays and we write MLA style essays with appropriate headers and the such. Is there an equivalent style two write a villanelle in?

Comment: So you’re asking how to _format_ a villanelle according to the MLA style guide?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for writing advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing a villanelle in class there is no MLA guidance on the formatting of original poetry. This makes sense as MLA is a set of style guidelines for "Writers of Research Papers."

If you are citing a villanelle you should use the guidelines here: http://libguides.pstcc.edu/content.php?pid=24540&sid=1751623